# Determining Length of Double Type Variable in C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am using the following code to come up with a number.

```
NSString *userNameOne = txtUserName.text;
double numOne = [userNameOne intValue];

double agedecade = numOne/10;
double betaage = 0.23260;
double meanage = 5.64301;
double one_age = agedecade - meanage;
double age_final_var =  one_age * betaage;
```

If the user input 55 into the `numOne` variable, the answer will be -.033264 using the above program.

However, if I do the same on a calculator I get -.033264126. I would like to get the extra three digits into my program. How do I get the missing three digits (...126) into my program above?

**
I happen to be using this code in an iPhone App, saying this in case this changes things.

Comment: The "answer" probably depends upon how you're printing it.  Increase the precision for printing, and you will see more digits.

Comment: You're using Objective-C, not plain C and you failed at indentation. Please be more careful when asking questions, these are the details that make it easier for others to provide you with useful answers.

Comment: are you talking about code indentation?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not in the double variable, but in the way you print it. Look at the function that prints it, and find a way to increase the amount of numbers after tghe decimal point.

Also, is it a typo, or again you have `intValue` instead of `doubleValue`? :>

Comment: yeah i asked this same time as i asked the other one regarding doubleValue. Will my data still be stored as the long decimal point?

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.15g", age_final_var];
```